# javascript tag-it allowed tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I need to allow users select ONLY allowed tags in tagSource.

Currently I have that:

```
var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
$("#myTags").tagit({
    tagSource: sampleTags 
});
```

[tag-it in GitHub](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)

[Tag-it! Usage Examples](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html)

Can you help me please with that?

Comment: `$("#myTags").tagit({
    availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this it will work

```
 var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
    $("#myTags").tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
         afterTagAdded: function (event, ui) {
        if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel, sampleTags) == -1) {
            $("#myTags").tagit("removeTagByLabel", ui.tagLabel);
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: but still user can create new tag.